# Difference between Data analytics and Data Analysis

Tags: data, data-analysis

What we are referring to when we say Data analytics and Data analysis?

Answer (score 0):

- Data analytics is the broad field of using data and tools to make business decisions.
- Data analysis, a subset of data analytics, refers to specific actions.

Find more at:

- [Difference between Data Analytics and Data Analysis](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-data-analytics-and-data-analysis/)
- [Comparison Table Between Data Analytics and Data Analysis](https://ppcexpo.com/blog/data-analysis-vs-data-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

Data Analytics involves the tools and resources used for data analysis.
Data Analysis is the work itself of analysing data.

Answer (score 0):

**Data Analysis:**

- Examines, cleans, transforms and models data to derive insights.
- Involves techniques such as descriptive statistics, data visualization, and exploratory data analysis.
- A broader term that encompasses the entire process of examining and interpreting data.

**Data Analytics:**

- Uses advanced techniques and tools to analyze large and complex datasets.
- Involves methods like machine learning, statistical modeling, and data mining.
- Specialized field that focuses on uncovering hidden patterns, correlations, and insights from data.